# License of Ubuntu MATE for commercial use

Tags: licensing, gpl, commercial, software

I would like to know what to be careful about using Ubuntu for commercial use.

I use Ubuntu MATE (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS), some packages, and applications I created. I only use my applicaton on my own system.

I think that if I install a package whose license is GPL and I use for my application, then I have to publish my source code of my application openly.

Do I have to publish openly in the case where I do not use a package but it is installed default in the distribution (Ubuntu MATE)?

Comment: 1) Do you distribute your application to others? Or do you only use it on your own system? 2) What do you mean with "use for my application"? Are these packages libraries that your application needs?

Comment: 1) I only use my applicaton on my own system.

Comment: 2) I mean that I use some libraries in my source (python and so on) and use some packages in my shell script. I would like to know if some packages which does not need for me are installed, the license problem occurs or not. If so, It means that I have to remove all unuse packages. Is it collect? or Do I not need to care about the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to make the source code available if you **distribute** your software. For example: offering it for download, sending it per email, selling it on CDs, installing it somewhere else.

This is the case for all FLOSS licenses (but some differ in what counts as distribution if servers are involved).

Whether or not this happens in a commercial context isn’t relevant. FLOSS licenses don’t differentiate between commercial and non-commerical.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. Thank you for your information.